# iis 8 fails loading owin.Oaut 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, owin, owin-security

When I Try to publish my Mvc App on iis * i got the following exception on Owin

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

here is in the Web.config file

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
```

This happens when i upgraded my Owin via Nuget. Any Help with this Issue???

Comment: Check if the dll is in the Bin directory of your iis website. MSBuild has an issue and sometimes not all dependencies are copied in the deploy package. If that is the case you should make sure it is added explicitly as a reference in your web project.

Comment: yes it is. when i look at the packages folder in the bin it does not change